# Posting a non-editable message to someones twitter

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm looking to build a twitter app. where the user connects, and then my application sends a tweet to their profile. Right now I have a tweet box with my message, but because it's editable it kind of defeats the purpose.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to disable (or make read-only) an HTML textarea/textfield?

Comment: No, I can't edit the textarea in @Anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) from the REST API. The users will authenticate with your app then you can show them the text that will be tweeted from their account next to a tweet button. When they hit the button just tweet the text as displayed. There isn't even a textarea for them to edit.

Comment: Would this be the best way to create an application that requires a tweet before entrance? Essentially I need to send the tweet to their profile, and then read it that it got sent and respond accordingly.

Comment: Yes. If the POST statues/update returns a HTTP 200 response you can give them access to the site. It will require them going through the Sign in with Twitter authorization flow before the tweet is sent though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop someone editing an input field, you could use something like:

```
onfocus="this.blur()"
```

in the HTML tag.